# unable to pause the sound when power button interrupt

Tags: android, andengine

Hi i am developing a game using andengine. I am unable to pause the music when power button interrupt. In manifest file I added:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

code- onPause and onResume methods

```
protected void onPause() {
    if(menumusic!=null)
    menumusic.pause();
    super.onPause();
    this.mEngine.onPause() ;
}
protected void onResume() {
    if(menumusic!=null)
    menumusic.resume();
    super.onResume();
    this.mEngine.onResume();
}
```

Problem is when power button is pressed `onPause()` method is calling and immediately `onResume()` is calling.
Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ..hope this may help u 
 use onWindowFocusChanged to help resume the game.  it works and music does not resume until  u r back in the game:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/onresume-being-called-when-device-should-be-paused-t8748.html#p42961